# Replace the value of an item in a JSON collection in Python

Tags: python, json, string

I have the following collection (response from http request):

```
[{'ParameterKey': 'AdminCCIDRBlock', 'ParameterValue': '10.10.196.0/23'}, 
 {'ParameterKey': 'MyParameter', 'ParameterValue': 'true'}]
```

I need to send the same collection in another request but I have to change the value of `MyParameter` to `false`. So the collection would become:

```
[{'ParameterKey': 'AdminCCIDRBlock', 'ParameterValue': '10.10.196.0/23'}, 
 {'ParameterKey': 'MyParameter', 'ParameterValue': 'false'}]
```

How can I do that nicely in Python?

Comment: Is it always in this format? Would `collection[1]['ParameterValue'] = 'false'` work?

Comment: no, `MyParameter` could be in any position of the collection, and there could be different parameters with boolean values

Comment: Loop through the list, test if `el['ParameterKey'] == 'MyParameter'` If it is, change `el['ParameterValue']` to `false`. What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would need to traverse the whole list anyway, so:

```
for d in collection:
    if d['ParameterKey'] == 'MyParameter':
        d['ParameterValue'] = 'false'
```